# How can I remove a node from a Binomial Queue?

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a function that would allow me to remove any node in a Binomial Queue.
I have the ability to find/delete the minimum element, and insert any element. My current approach is to make a vector that holds all the minimum elements, delete them until I find the desired element, delete it, then put all elements back in the Binomial Queue:

```
 void Remove(const Element & x){
      vector<Element> temp;
      while (findMin() != x)
      {
        temp.push_back(findMinIndex());
        deleteMin();
      }
      deleteMin();
      for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
      {
        insert(temp[i]);
      }
    }
```

Note: `template <typename Element>`

The problem is, I get a segmentation error, which appears to be coming from the vector, though I have no confidence in this. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Other relevant code is down here:

```
   const int findMin( ) const
    {
        int i;
        int minIdx;

        for( i = 0; Trees[ i ] == nullptr; ++i ) //Trees is a vector of nodes
            ;

        for( minIdx= i; i < theTrees.size( ); ++i )
            if( Trees[ i ] != nullptr &&
                Trees[ i ]->element < Trees[ minIdx]->element ) //Element is the actual Node value
                minIdx= i;

       return Trees[ minIdx ]->element;
    }
```

One instance was a tree composed of the numbers: 12, 29, 113, 101, 0, 74, 22, 3, 17, 4 (not in order), and I called remove on 5,2,0,1,113, 74, 22, 5 and 2 weren't there, and my test file printed that they weren't found, and upon 0, the segmentation fault occurs (specifically when the vector is created).

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: `//Trees is a vector of nodes` -- It doesn't contain nodes.  It contains pointers.